# OWL carousel does not work in RTL format in wordpress theme

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am using a wordpress theme to uses OWL carousel. There are 3 photos, but only the first photo displayed.

Link:
[http://www.otoshow.ir/listings/کارکرده-2008-325i-کروک-ب-ام-و/](http://www.otoshow.ir/listings/%da%a9%d8%a7%d8%b1%da%a9%d8%b1%d8%af%d9%87-2008-325i-%da%a9%d8%b1%d9%88%da%a9-%d8%a8-%d8%a7%d9%85-%d9%88/)

I have found a related issue with the position of the photos:

- (0px,0px,0px) first photo, ok.
- (-815px,0px,0px) second photo
- (-1630px,0px,0px) third photo
- and so on....

If I could change - to +, then this would work. How can I set this to use an increment of +815px.

Code below:

```
/**
 * Animates the stage.
 * @public
 * @param {Number} coordinate - The coordinate in pixels.
 */
Owl.prototype.animate = function(coordinate) {
    this.trigger('translate');
    this.state.inMotion = this.speed() > 0;

    if (this.support3d) {
        this.$stage.css({
            transform: 'translate3d(' + coordinate + 'px' + ',0px, 0px)',
            transition: (this.speed() / 1000) + 's'
        });
    } else if (this.state.isTouch) {
        this.$stage.css({
            left: coordinate + 'px'
        });
    } else {
        this.$stage.animate({
            left: coordinate
        }, this.speed() / 1000, this.settings.fallbackEasing, $.proxy(function() {
            if (this.state.inMotion) {
                this.transitionEnd();
            }
        }, this));
    }
};
```

Comment: Corrected grammar to make the question more understandable to a wider audience. Updated link to display UTF-8 for non-latin (Persian?) characters instead of encoded URL format.

Answer (score 1):

Owl Carousel supports rtl already. You have to edit "owl.carousel.js" file.
At the end of the file there are many options as follows.

```
afterAction : false,
startDragging : false,
afterLazyLoad: false
```

Simply add "rtl: true"

```
afterAction : false,
startDragging : false,
afterLazyLoad: false,
rtl: true
```

And for "FooGallery Owl Carousel Template" plugin, edit "gallery-owl-carousel.php".

Add "rtl: true" at the end of the file as follows.

```
autoplayHoverPause: <?php echo $pause; ?>,
lazyLoad: true,
autoWidth: <?php echo $autowidth; ?>,
rtl: true
```

Comment: What about add-on update if I update add-on all of my changes will delete? what we should do to solve this problem?